# Optimize Webview in Android App

Tags: android, web, webview, activity-transition

when we add an an activity with a webview in it , it will load the website. But when we click some links on the webpage we gets redirected to some other page.Now if we press the back button, instead of redirecting back to the previous webpage, it redirects to the previous **activity** How can we fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override this :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack())
        webView.goBack();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override the onBackPressed in your activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()){
         webView.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```